# Check for multiple values with JS include

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, include

There is a function that checks the content of the url with `window.location.href`. If the URL contains a specific string it should return true:

```
const doesItContain = () => {
  const url = window.location.href;
  return url.includes('/items');
};
```

This works fine, if the url contains `/items` it returns `true`. The issue comes when it needs to check for multiple strings (multiple pages) and return true if one of them are present. For example:

```
const doesItContain = () => {
  const url = window.location.href;
  return url.includes('/items', '/users');
};
```

It returns true only for the first string in the list. Is there a way to check for both or more than one string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.includes` expects one argument. The other arguments are ignored.

You can use `some` to iterate an array of strings and check if at least one element fullfils the condition:

```
const doesItContain = () => {
  const url = window.location.href;
  return ['/items', '/users'].some(el => url.includes(el));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, separating each of the strings to check with `|`.

```js
return /\/items|\/users/.test(url);
```

Comment: can you provide a way to dynamically create the regex for different situations

Comment: @YoussefHossam Yes, use the `RegExp` constructor.